# Import Swift charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, frameworks

I am currently trying to import the Swift charts framework to my projects but got some problems.
It keeps saying "no such module Charts"
Does anyone have a instruction of how to do it or could give me one? The ones i found are not working at all
Thanks!

Comment: how are you installing the framework

Comment: i use the instructions of danielgindi. First drawing the file to my project, than selecting the framework at target settings

Comment: Go for pods .. It will be very easy for you

Comment: I have the same problem but rebuilding didn't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build project first by <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or *Product -> Build*.