# Swift Charts not importing into project correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui-charts

I am trying to adopt [Swift Charts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts) but after adding it to my project and importing it in the file, I am still seeing warning messages in Xcode. I've read [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263413/import-swift-charts) and tried suggestions routes like clearing the cache, resetting Xcode, removing/re-adding the framework, etc. Nothing works.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Charts


class MainQuickMenu: UIViewController {
    
    ... skipping IBOutlets, variables, lifecycle, etc...

    // First error thrown below "Cannot find type 'BarChartView' in scope"
    func createBarChart(data: [NSObject], containerView: UIView) -> BarChartView {
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -90, to: Date()) ?? Date()
    
    var dateCounts = [String: Int]()        
    for task in data {
        if let createdDate = task.value(forKey: "createdDate") as? Date, createdDate >= startDate {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // You can adjust the date format as needed
            let dateString = formatter.string(from: createdDate)
            dateCounts[dateString, default: 0] += 1
        }
    }
    
    let chartView = BarChartView()
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    var index = 0
    ....
```

Tried so far:

- I've tried with and without Charts.framework added to "Frameworks, libraries..."
- I updated my entire project and code to conform to an iOS16 deployment target, as that's a requirement for Swift Charts.
- I added SwiftUI to the file, even though the project is UIKit based, as I was willing to learn SwiftUI and adopt it for this view but still the errors persist.
- I also tried importing SwiftUI and adding a standalone (outside of the class) struct using Chart components, to see if it was my class, but Chart classes still got errors.

Adding images below of configs as well.

Errors

[image]

Swift Charts Framework Imported

[image]

iOS16 deployment target

[image]

My goal here is just to understand how to begin to work with these Charts classes without the errors. Am I not importing Swift Charts correctly? To be clear, I'm not looking for an actual solution to the charts themselves.

Comment: There is an official swift charts now. There is a solution out there where you can change the name of the pod to avoid the conflicts. I don’t have a link.

Comment: There is no such thing as `BarChartView` in [SwiftUI Chart](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts). You have `Chart{...}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it wrong.

1. `BarChartView` is a component of `Charts` (DGChart). It's on [this repo](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).
2. As you mentioned above, you're trying to adapt the native `Swift Charts`. However, it also has the same name as DGChart by `import Charts`, that's why these errors show up.

BarChart in Swift Charts framework is something like:

```swift
Chart {
    BarMark(x: ..., y: ...)
}
```